# how to parse data from json file in flutter?

Tags: flutter-dependencies

Error on line 60, column 2 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
â•·
60 â”‚  assets:
â”‚  ^
â•µ
Process finished with exit code 65

i need to show data from json file

Answer (score 0):

you can user [dart:convert](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html) API. you can use [JsonCodec class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/dart-convert/JsonCodec-class.html)  to parse data from json file.

here is an example .

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 30,
  "email": "johndoe@example.com"
}

String jsonData = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
dynamic data = json.decode(jsonData);
String name = data['name'];
int age = data['age'];
String email = data['email'];
```